# Clicar em em Notification Desktop e ir pra mesma janela sem dar o refresh na página

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

estou desenvolvendo um chat com WebSocket e estou com um problema, quando eu mando uma mensagem para um amigo, ele recebe a notificação desktop (do Browser que ele estiver) e quando ele clica na notificação ele vai pra janela da conversa da pessoa que mandou a mensagem para ele.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu quero é pelo menos quando o usuário clicar na notificação vá para a aba onde está o chat sem dar o refresh da página, o trecho que fiz foi assim, mas ele atualiza a página e não vai para a "aba do chat":

```
notification.onclick = function () {
     window.open('http://localhost/pullchat', '_self');
};
```

O Código completo da função de notificação:

```
    //Função de notificação de mensagens
        function notifyMe(nome, mensagem, id) {
              if (!Notification) {
                alert('Notifications are supported in modern versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Firefox.');
                return;
              }

              if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
                Notification.requestPermission();

              var notification = new Notification( nome, {
                icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
                body: mensagem,
              });

//------------------------AQUI QUE ESTÁ O PROBLEMA-------------------------------
              notification.onclick = function () {
                window.open('http://localhost/pullchat', '_self');
              };
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `window.focus()`, contudo é possível que isto não funcione em todos os browsers, uma vez que as configurações de segurança de cada um podem variar de acordo com as politicas de privacidade do usuário.

Existem dois tópicos no stackOverflow ingles que podem te ajudar:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016999/how-to-get-focus-to-the-tab-when-a-desktop-notification-is-clicked-in-firefox
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906976/how-to-get-focus-to-a-chrome-tab-which-created-desktop-notification

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com essa pergunta no [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906976/how-to-get-focus-to-a-chrome-tab-which-created-desktop-notification), basta você usar `window.focus()` no lugar onde está usando `window.open`.

Isso leva o foco para a a janela que gerou a notificação.

Ou seja, faça

```
notification.onclick = function () {
     window.focus();
};
```